# How to make array ref in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

Here actually I want to make the service collection that contain the array of references of the ratings. when a user rate a service than an element is pushed in the array containing reference of user , service ID no and the rating.

`Service Model` like this:

```
    var ServiceSchema = new Schema({
      user_id:{
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'please provide user id']
      },
      name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'please enter your name']
      },
      rating : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'rating' }],
    });
```

`Rating schema`:

```
    var RatingSchema = Schema({
      S_id :   { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId},
      Rating : Number,
      By  :    { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId}
    });
```

`user schema`:

```
    var UserSchema = new Schema({
      id: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: [true, 'please enter your id']
      },
      password: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'please enter your password']
      },
      name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'please enter your name']
      },
      type: {
        type: [{
          type: String,
          enum: ['visitor', 'seller']
        }],
        default: ['visitor']
      },
   });
```

and I have defined the export as:

```
    module.exports = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema, 'users');
    module.exports = mongoose.model('service', ServiceSchema, 'service');
    module.exports = mongoose.model('rating', RatingSchema, 'rating');
```

I want to make a function called rate but I am not getting how to make it.

```
    exports.rate = function(req, res) {
      var curr_service = new Service(req.body, result);
      new_service.save(function(err, service) {
        if (err)
          res.send(err);
        res.json(service);
      });
    };
```

So far I have done this.

Can someone help me to understand what should I do now? because I haven't find that much about `mongoose` to add ref in array...

Answer (score 0):

In my case. This error was happening because instead of putting `{es_indexed: true}` inside the object declaration, I was putting it in the object that was using. For example:

```
const Client: Schema({
  name: {type: String, es_indexed: true},
  address: {type: Adress, es_indexed: true} //Wrong, causing error
})

Adress: Schema({ 
  address: {type: String},
  zipCode:  {type: Number}
})
```

The correct way to use, is putting `es_indexed: true` into primitive types inside "Adress" schema declaration.

```
const Client: Schema({
  name: {type: String, es_indexed: true},
  address: {type: Adress} //Right way
})

Adress: Schema({ 
  address: {type: String, es_indexed: true},
  zipCode:  {type: Number, es_indexed: true}
})
```

I hope it was helpful